# updateMany in mongoose does not update property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For some reason I cannot update properties in my documents using `updateMany` in mongoose(5.8.10). Here's my query:

```
Booking.updateMany({ sessionId }, { "isPaid": true } );
```

At the beginning documents with above `sessionId` have `isPaid` flag set to false. Now I want switch this flag to false in all those documents. This however does not update properties.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that it does not work without the callback like so:

```
      Booking.updateMany({ sessionId }, { "isPaid": true }, null, (error, res) => {
        if(error) {
          console.log("Something went wrong when updating data!");
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `Booking.updateMany({ sessionId }, { "isPaid": true } );` does not execute the request to database. It's a query ready to be executed. You can do it by either passing callback as third parameter or by using `.then()` syntax.

*Callback* variant:

```
Booking.updateMany({ sessionId }, { "isPaid": true }, (err, data) => {
...
});
```

*Then* variant:

```
Booking.updateMany({ sessionId }, { "isPaid": true })
.then(data => {})
.catch(err => {})
```

Source: [Mongoose Queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)